# Como fazer o custom select da tela "Fornecedores" buscar informações (NomeEmpresa) na tabela "Empresa"

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, aplicação-web

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em Asp.Net usando MVC 5. Criei um `select` na tela de Fornecedores e gostaria de saber como posso buscar as informações do meu banco e mostrá-las nesse custom.

Minha aplicação possui duas telas: Empresas e Fornecedores. Na tela de fornecedores, possuo um `select` onde gostaria de pegar os nomes de empresas cadastrados na tela de "Empresas".

No banco de dados possuo duas tabelas: Fornecedores e Empresas.

Código do `select`:

```cs
       <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col-7">
            <label for="txtNome">Empresa:</label>
            <select name="Empresa" id="txtEmpresa"  class="custom-select">
                <option selected>Escolha uma empresa...</option>
                <option value="@Model.Empresa">One</option>
                <option value="@Model.Empresa">Two</option>
                <option value="@Model.Empresa">Three</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <label>&nbsp</label>
            <div class="mb-3">
                <a href="~/Empresas/AddEdit" class="btn btn-outline-info"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i>Nova Empresa</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Por que você não usa Razor? Outro detalhe, adiciona o fonte da sua `controller`.

Comment: Conseguiu verificar a resposta?

Answer (score 0):

Considerando o próprio template MVC do Visual Studio e adicionando os `Controllers` e `Views` usando a opção `Add > New Scaffolded Item...`, o resultado que vc espera pode ser obtido com os seguintes métodos de criação e edição:

```cs
        // GET: Suppliers/Create
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewData["CompanyId"] = new SelectList(_context.Company, "Id", "Name");
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Suppliers/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,Name,CompanyId")] Supplier supplier)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Add(supplier);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            ViewData["CompanyId"] = new SelectList(_context.Company, "Id", "Name", supplier.CompanyId);
            return View(supplier);
        }

        // GET: Suppliers/Edit/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var supplier = await _context.Supplier.FindAsync(id);
            if (supplier == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            ViewData["CompanyId"] = new SelectList(_context.Company, "Id", "Name", supplier.CompanyId);
            return View(supplier);
        }

        // POST: Suppliers/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("Id,Name,CompanyId")] Supplier supplier)
        {
            if (id != supplier.Id)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    _context.Update(supplier);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
                catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
                {
                    if (!SupplierExists(supplier.Id))
                    {
                        return NotFound();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            ViewData["CompanyId"] = new SelectList(_context.Company, "Id", "Name", supplier.CompanyId);
            return View(supplier);
        }
```

A parte importante de todo esse código é `new SelectList(_context.Company, "Id", "Name")`. O 1o parâmetro do `SelectList` são os objetos listados, o 2o é o `id` utilizado como chave e `Name` é a propriedade que vc deseja exibir no `select`. A `view` é exatamente a criada pelo Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Considere o seguinte cenário:

**Na Controller:**

```
List<Empresa> lstEmpresa = new List<Empresa>();
lstEmpresa.Add(new Empresa() { ID = 1, Nome = "Empresa 01"});
lstEmpresa.Add(new Empresa() { ID = 2, Nome = "Empresa 02"});
lstEmpresa.Add(new Empresa() { ID = 3, Nome = "Empresa 03"});

ViewBag.EmpresaList = new SelectList(lstEmpresa, "ID", "Nome");
```

**Na View:**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Empresa, new SelectList(ViewBag.EmpresaList, "Value", "Text"), new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Existem vários modelos de preencher, em minhas aplicações que desenvolvo utilizo este conceito básico. Preencher o List, você escolhe a forma como sua aplicação faz isto, mas a estrutura apresentada é o modelo básico para entendimento.